# fancybox 3 white overlay on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, fancybox-3

I am working on web using fancybox 3 for videos, it works smooth on all devices but on iPad, if u cleared all web history then launch the site and click on the video for the first time, a white overlay appears over the video, then if refresh then click on the video again, it works fine no more white div.

1 more thing is that the videos are under slick slider.

For reference, I am here by attaching images of the issue.

[image]
[image]